# How to include a helper from the ApplicationController into a Sidekiq worker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper, sidekiq

This is my `ApplicationController` controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :is_admin?

  def is_admin?
    ...
  end
end
```

I am trying to use this helper `is_admin?` in the Sidekiq worker. So far, I am including there this:

```
class GenerateInvoiceWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(product_id)
    av = ActionView::Base.new()
    av.view_paths = ActionController::Base.view_paths

    av.class_eval do
      include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
      include ApplicationHelper
    end

    ...
  end
end
```

How to make the helper method available in the worker?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You're WAY over thinking it:

```
class GenerateInvoiceWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include MyHelper

  def perform(product_id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Extract `is_admin?` into `ApplicationHelper` or any other module. Remember helpers are nothing but ruby modules. Then include that module (be it `ApplicationHelper` or any other custom helper, both in `ApplicationController` and in `GenerateInvoiceWorker`.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include ApplicationHelper

end

class GenerateInvoiceWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include ApplicationHelper

  def perform(product_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Draham. However, `is_admin?` is not in the `ApplicationHelper` file, but in the `ApplicationController` file as a method. How to extract this one?

Comment: Just move the method `is_admin?` from `application_controller.rb` to `application_helper.rb`.